# ALSA OSS Emulation won't work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, emulation, alsa

Ok I spend the last 4 hours or so trying to get this to work, without any success :(

I'm on Ubuntu9.10 with pulseaudio setup, everything works fine so far. But when I try to record my Desktop with xvidcap or recordmydesktop I'm unable to get the sound working.

xvidcap uses only OSS so I tried to setup the emulation by loading the kernel modules and adding the following lines to /etc/modules:

```
alias sound-service-0-0 snd-mixer-oss
alias sound-service-0-1 snd-seq-oss
alias sound-service-0-3 snd-pcm-oss
alias sound-service-0-8 snd-seq-oss
alias sound-service-0-12 snd-pcm-oss
```

But it still won't work :(

According to the web recordmydesktop should work with "pulse" set as audio device, but it doesn't. Even alsa doesn't work, either it fails to open the device or it can't recognize the sound format.

For info I'm on a Vaio Laptop with an Intel HDA Audio Card.

**EDIT**
That's what rec is giving me:

```
ivo@ivo:~$ rec /dev/dsp test.wav
rec FAIL formats: can't determine type of file `/dev/dsp'
ivo@ivo:~$ rec /dev/mixer test.wav
rec FAIL formats: can't determine type of file `/dev/mixer'
ivo@ivo:~$ rec /dev/dsp test.wav
rec FAIL formats: can't determine type of file `/dev/dsp'
ivo@ivo:~$ padsp rec /dev/dsp test.wav
rec FAIL formats: can't determine type of file `/dev/dsp'
ivo@ivo:~$ padsp rec /dev/mixer test.wav
rec FAIL formats: can't open input file `/dev/mixer': Input/output error
ivo@ivo:~$ aoss rec /dev/dsp test.wav
rec FAIL formats: can't determine type of file `/dev/dsp'
ivo@ivo:~$ aoss rec /dev/mixer test.wav
rec FAIL formats: can't determine type of file `/dev/mixer'
ivo@ivo:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the pulseaudio oss emulation by running `padsp xvidcap`.

record-my-desktop works quite well with jackd, but I have not tried it with other audio frameworks.

Comment: When I try this /dev/dsp is accepted, but there's no sound coming from the device, /dev/mixer crashes the progam. Also in jackd I have the problem that I can't select the mixer or anything besides the built in microphone :(

Comment: Just tried -M and -D both don't work when I try to access the mixer I get:[oss @ 0xafe62650]Soundcard does not support 16 bit sample format. With -D I get: [oss @ 0xa1e7ee0]/dev/dsp: Device or resource busy

Comment: OK! Got it to work with record my desktop :)
This will do the job: padsp recordmydesktop --device /dev/dsp --buffer-size 1024

Since I didn't know of padsp before I'll select this as the answer. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stupid answer, but I've used the alsa-oss package.  This allows you to run an oss-based application using the aoss wrapper.  Once you have ALSA working and sound plays, all you have to do is install the package.  Then, run the program using the aoss wrapper.

Example: /usr/bin/aoss /usr/bin/mserv